# Creating Dummy Variables from data frame

Tags: r, bayesian

I need to do a Bayesian linear regression (using the rethinking package) which requires my categorical variable be numeric (I think), so I'm trying to create dummy variables so that different categories are represented by (0,1,2,3...). I've simulated some data below to show you what my data looks like. Keep in mind that my actual data contains many more categorical variables that are represented here, so using a bunch of ifelse functions wouldn't be ideal:

```
#simulated data
X <- data.frame(
    Longest.axis = rnorm(50,10,5),
    Time..hrs. = round(runif(50,0,4)),
    Strain = sapply(1:50,function(x) {ifelse(x<12,"Msmeg_2788","Msmeg_WT")}),
    Item.Name = sapply(1:50,
        function(x) 
            {ifelse(x<6,"Q109.jpg",
            ifelse(x<20,"Q340.jpg",
                ifelse(x<40,"Q11.jpg","Q230.jpg")
            )
        )}
    )
)
```

And bellow I show my attempt to create dummy variables:

```
#create dummy variables
Straindummy <- model.matrix(X$Strain)
Item.Namedummy <- model.matrix(X$Item.Name)
```

it returns the following error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

And here is my attempt to do a multivariate Bayesian linear regression just in case you need it to suggest what I should do:

```
library(rethinking)
model <- map(
    alist(
        X$Longest.Axis ~ dnorm(mu,sigma),
        mu <- a + b1*Straindummy+b2*Item.Namedummy+b3*X$Time..hrs.,
        a ~ dnorm(10,10),
        b1 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        b2 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        b3 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        sigma ~ dunif(0,10)
    ),
    data = X )
```

Thank you if you can offer any help!

Comment: Try `model.matrix(~ Item.Name, X)` or `model.matrix(~ Strain, X)`  If you don't need the intercept, `model.matrix(~ Strain-1, X)`

Comment: I think you want `mu =` or maybe `mu ~`, not `mu <-` inside your `alist()`. And as akrun shows, give `model.matrix` a formula and a data frame, not just a column. (And especially not a column that doesn't exist)

Comment: The short answer is ... Don't do that. It's not needed and distracts you from identifying the real error and prevents you from using R's formula mechanism efficiently.

Comment: I was in Seattle for 9 years, moved away about a year ago. Haven't lived in the Bay Area since '96

Comment: @Gregor: Must have you conflated with another SO regular. I grew up in Traverse City, so was surprised when I chacked yer profile.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any of the model.matrix stuff, since R factors are numeric "under the hood". But you do need to install (and you probably have but didn't describe how to do it for the next readers) the dependencies and package from Github:

```
install.packages(c("coda","mvtnorm","devtools","loo"))
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rmcelreath/rethinking")
```

Then after correcting the variable name error, the original code runs with the original column names:

```
 library(rethinking)
model <- map(
    alist(
        Longest.axis ~ dnorm(mu,sigma),
        mu <- a + b1*X$Strain+b2*X$Item.Name+b3*X$Time..hrs.,
        a ~ dnorm(10,10),
        b1 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        b2 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        b3 ~ dnorm(0,1),
        sigma ~ dunif(0,10)
    ),
    data = X )

model
#--------------------------------------
Maximum a posteriori (MAP) model fit

Formula:
Longest.axis ~ dnorm(mu, sigma)
mu <- a + b1 * X$Strain + b2 * X$Item.Name + b3 * X$Time..hrs.
a ~ dnorm(10, 10)
b1 ~ dnorm(0, 1)
b2 ~ dnorm(0, 1)
b3 ~ dnorm(0, 1)
sigma ~ dunif(0, 10)

MAP values:
          a          b1          b2          b3       sigma 
10.73889375 -0.21053314  0.01836911 -0.24736940  4.69900162 

Log-likelihood: -148.32
```

And furthermore it runs correctly if you omit the X$-method of accessing the data:

```
...
mu <- a + b1*Strain+b2*Item.Name+b3*X$Time..hrs.,
...
```

Properly written functions will interpret a factor variable by expanding the full model matrix correctly in the context of the `data`-argument. So You should NOT need to access the variables as `objecName$columnName`, but rather just supply a formula with column names and the object to the `data=`-argument. This applies to both numeric and factor variables. Look at the results of:

```
 object <- data.frame(x=runif(10), y=factor( sample(c('a','b','c'),10,rep=TRUE)))
 model.matrix(~x+y, object)
#----------------------
(Intercept)          x yb yc
1            1 0.04942913  0  0
2            1 0.92403817  1  0
3            1 0.46485707  0  1
4            1 0.57529925  1  0
5            1 0.47036022  0  1
6            1 0.63165954  0  0
7            1 0.11975911  0  1
8            1 0.13187866  1  0
9            1 0.25253765  0  1
10           1 0.52289041  1  0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 0 1 2 2
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$y
[1] "contr.treatment
```